# React - useContext() is returning "undefined"

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I created a ContextProvider to pass the image to a child component, but it's returning "undefined" for some reason.

Here's my folder structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg84Z.png)

Here's my source code for ContextProvider.jsx:

```
import React, { createContext } from "react";
import logo from "../assets/logo.jpeg";

export const BrandContext = createContext();

export default function ContextProvider({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <BrandContext.Provider value={{imgSrc: logo}}>{children}</BrandContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here's my source code for BrandComponent.jsx:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { BrandContext } from "../../context/ContextProvider";

export default function BrandComponent({
  logoImageSrc,
  customWidth,
  customHeight,
}) {
  const brandContext = useContext(BrandContext);

  return (
    <div className="logo d-flex flex-direction-row custom-width-sm-30 custom-width-md-40 ms-5">
      <h1 className="navbar-brand fs-2 custom-font-family-teko custom-color-darkpurple">
        Gym
        <img
          src={brandContext}
          alt="gym-bro-logo"
          className={`custom-width-${customWidth} custom-height-${customHeight}`}
        />
        Bro
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried to pass a boolean value (i.e. <BrandContext.Provider value={true}>...) instead, and it still returns "undefined".

Comment: Is `BrandComponent` a descendant of `BrandContext.Provider`?

Comment: ah thanks all for the support, I just noticed that I didn't wrap the parent component with ContextProvider, works now!

Answer (score 0):

When you are consuming the context, you are receiving the variable which is passed in value. In your case you have:

```
<BrandContext.Provider value={{imgSrc: logo}}>{children}</BrandContext.Provider>
```

The variable passed to value is an object with a key imgSrc and his value the logo. If you want to consume that value, you have to pass  "src={brandContext.imgSrc}".

I want to mention that the file, where the ContextProvider is used is not given. Make sure BrandComponent is a children of the ContextProvider.

Answer (score 0):

Did you wrap your `BrandComponent.jsx` within the Context Provider?

If you didn't wrap the `BrandComponent.jsx` within the Context Provider, it will return undefined.

```
<div className='App'>
  <ContextProvider>
    <BrandComponent customWidth={10} customHeight={10} />
  </ContextProvider>
</div>
```

This is how you should wrap your BrandComponent within ContextProvider.